# HOW TO MAKE A DYNAMIC PROFILE PAGE?

Tags: html, wordpress, content-management-system

I have a client who wants me to make a website that contains a page showing the profiles of people who work for my client. Each such profile page would have a photograph, the name of the person and a description of the person. My client wants to control what photo is uploaded, and he wants to add the name and description himself. People have suggested that I use a small content management system (CMS), but I don't know anything about CMSes.

How might I satisfy my client as quickly as possible (pointer to a tutorial, other)?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)? Did you pick the [tag:wordpress] tag because you are using WordPress?

Comment: Having read the question, the fastest way I would suggest to satisfy the client would be to recommend another developer.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: I picked wordpress tag because someone recommended me to use it, but I don't know how to grab the content from Wordpress and put it on my design. :S

Comment: Try searching for terms like 'custom author page' or 'user profile page' in Google.

Comment: Also take a look at this http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_currentuserinfo

Comment: STOP SHOUTING! WE CAN HEAR YOU!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, for such small tasks no CMS (I mean WP or Drupal) is necessarily needed - customizing one for your needs will me much more painful, than adding a few PHP lines to your HTML files.

To make your website able to get data, you will have to make it perform some server-side operations. This is most often done by PHP scripts (of which you could have heard of). If you are familiar with it, you can just skip the next paragraph.

PHP is a really easy and powerful language to learn, but bear in mind that if you learn some bad practices at the very beginning, you will be having a bad time trying to get rid of them later. But for this single purpose, you should take look at PHP tutorial at Codecademy (well, SO does not allow me to post more than 2 links so far, so you will have to google it by yourself :(). By the way, there are lots of tutorials on Youtube for  guys just like you - just type in something like "php cms tutorial" and they will show up - but they might be at least a little confusing for people, who have never experienced PHP before.

First of all, determine which part of your website will be affected by variables. In these places you will have to put PHP's echoes, such as

```
<?php echo $name ?>

<?php echo $description ?>
```

or, in case of an image:

```
<img alt="some alt text" src="<?php echo $image_location ?>">
```

If you have it, your next step will be writing a PHP code, that will perform:

1. Reading from a data source (text file, database)
2. Assigning each data part to a specific variable
3. `echo` ing it in the HTML file

Sound pretty easy. So you have an image, a title, and a description. Well, title and a description may be kept in a single text file. The content inside will be separated by `explode()` function, for example if you keep your data in the `x.txt` file, that you will read in to a variable by the `file_get_contents()` function:

`Name|||Bio`

the `explode("|||", $data)` function will return an array:

`[0] => "Name"`
`[1] => "Bio"`

Well, of course this is not the most elegant way, but definitely the easiest. Anyway, it covers the reading part.

For the writing part, that will be mostly used by your client, you should make a set of HTML files containing forms, that will forward to a PHP script executing validating, escaping and writing instructions. Get familar with superglobal array `$_POST`, functions such as `htmlspecialchars()`, `nl2br()`, `fwrite()`. You would also like to set a some kind of an [authentication](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php). For image upload, just check out [file upload tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp). Having your files location, you can store it in your files, and then put it in the `src` attribute of your `img` tag.

Comment: Very nice answer, pity that's a low quality question that may certainly end closed and deleted, losing you any points gained...

Comment: Thank you, yes I'm checking codeacademy and Lynda PHP stuff, since I only have background on HTML and CSS. Thanks for such a complete answer, I'm also going to have a look at you tube as you said!